# Is Binomial:Gamma ever an integer?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, gamma-function

We consider:

$$\dfrac{\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(k)\Gamma(n-k)}\quad\quad[1]$$

for $n,k\in\mathbb{R}$.

Is $[1]$ ever an integer, except for the obvious?

Comment: I'm almost sure this is an unsatisfying answer but: it seems to me the obvious answer is yes. Fixing $k$, we see that as $n \to \infty$, the expression goes to $\infty$ as well. Thus, being continuous, it must pass through every (positive) integer. It would be difficult to see what values of $n$ produce these values though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, rather trivially so.  The function you describe is the reciprocal of a beta function $B(a,b)$ for a suitable bijection between $(a,b)$ and $(n,k)$; explicitly, $$n = a+b, \quad k = a$$ is one such one-to-one mapping.  Consequently, if there exist $n, k \in \mathbb R$ such that $[1]$ is a (positive) integer $m$, then there exists $a, b \in \mathbb R$ such that $B(a,b) = 1/m$.  The level curves of the beta function in the first quadrant show that there exist infinitely many (non-integer) ordered pairs $(a,b)$ that satisfy this condition for each $m \in \mathbb Z^+$.

Comment: Seems to be correct